# viewDidLoad is not called after the setting of no storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, programmatically-created

What I would like to do is to create UIImageView without storyboard, but failed to let it show. At first I deleted `storyboard`, `LaunchScreen.xib` and `Main StoryBoard file base name` from info.plist. and then what I created is as follows:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIImage *imageData =[UIImage imageNamed:@"aaa.png"];

    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 100, 100)];
    myImage.image = imageData;
    [self.view addSubview:myImage];

}
```

I am a beginner and couldn't find any solution.
Does anybody know how to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Xcode 6.4

OSX 10.10.5

Comment: I didnt see any storyboard that is loaded programmatically in ur code, and u didnt set the root controller too. You cannot create a storyboard programmatically. Either u can load it programmatically or load xibs!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set your window's root view controller to an instance of ViewController

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

You'll also have to import ViewController.h at the top of your AppDelegate file

Comment: It works! You really helped me out. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NI No problem. Please accept my answer if you get a chance